# Inserting data into column family

Tags: java, cassandra

I have started working with Cassandra database recently and I was trying to insert some data into one of my column family that I have created. Below is the code by which I am trying to insert into Cassandra database.

In my case I have around `20 columns` in my column family so that means I need to add below line

```
mutator.newColumn("Column Name", "Column Value");
```

**Twenty times** in my below code which looks ugly to me. Is there any way, I can simplify the below method either by using reflection or some other way so that If I have more than 20  columns, I should not keep on adding extra line in my below code.

```
for (int userId = id; userId < id + noOfTasks; userId++) {

    Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator(thrift_connection_pool);

    mutator.writeColumns(column_family, String.valueOf(userId),
            mutator.newColumnList(
            mutator.newColumn("a_account", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_advertising", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_avg_selling_price_main_cats", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_cat_and_keyword_rules", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_csa_categories_purchased", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_customer_service", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_demographic", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_favorite_searches", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_favorite_sellers", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_financial", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}")
            mutator.newColumn(some othe column, its value)
            .....
            .....
            .....
            ));


    mutator.execute(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
}
```

Any help in simplifying the above method will be of great help to me. I was thinking of using a `Constant` class file like below which will have below methods for each column:

```
public static void setAccount_epu(final Mutator mutator, final int userId) throws SQLException {

    final String A_ACCOUNT = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}";

    mutator.newColumn("a_account", A_ACCOUNT);
}

public static void setAdvertising_epu(final Mutator mutator, final int userId) throws SQLException {

    final String A_ADVERTISING = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"thirdPartyAdsOnEbay\":null,\"ebayAdsOnThirdParty\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":2}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}";

    mutator.newColumn("a_advertising", A_ADVERTISING);
}

public static void setClv_info_epu(final Mutator mutator, final int userId) throws SQLException {

    final String A_CLV_INFO = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"tenureSiteReg\":null,\"bghtItms\":48,\"pnlValue\":105.478409,\"byrSgmnt\":2,\"cstmrId\":\"814296998\",\"slrRevRnk\":-99.0,\"soldItms\":0,\"slrSgmnt\":6,\"byrRevRnk\":0.013,\"mainAcct\":78,\"gmv\":0.0,\"cstmrRevRnk\":0.021,\"pnlRev\":313.438843,\"cstmrSgmnt\":51,\"gmb\":4674.76,\"totalVal\":142.536293,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":42}],\"lmd\":20130206212543}";

    mutator.newColumn("a_clv_info", A_CLV_INFO);

}

public static void setClv_behavior_epu(final Mutator mutator, final int userId) throws SQLException {

    final String A_CLV_BEHAVIOR = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"behaviorInfo\":\"111:0.56,113:0.33,116:0.10,118:0.03,117:0.00,69:0.00,73:0.00,115:0.00,108:0.00\",\"usrId\":1001116884,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":41}],\"lmd\":20130206212543}";

    mutator.newColumn("a_clv_behavior", A_CLV_BEHAVIOR);
}

public static void setClv_churn_epu(final Mutator mutator, final int userId) throws SQLException {

    final String A_CLV_CHURN = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"churnPrdctvDecileNum\":9,\"churnPrdctvScoreVal\":671.38116,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":44}],\"lmd\":20130206212543}";

    mutator.newColumn("a_clv_churn", A_CLV_CHURN);

}
```

Can I then use some reflection around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pattern is alway the same, I am right? Then you could just do:

```
String commonColumnValue = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"
String[] columns = {"a_account", "a_advertising", ..., "a_financial"} //extend by your needs

for(String columnsItem : columns)
    mutator.newColumn(columnsItem, commonColumnValue);
```

Comment: No that is for demonstration purpose. In general it will be different for all the columns.

Comment: ok. How should we help, if we do not know the code? I do not understand the question then.